# Simple Model for Accessing Multiple Google Analytics Accounts

Tags: python, google-analytics, oauth-2.0

I am looking for some clarification on how the Google OAuth 2.0 architecture handles the management of multiple Google Analytics accounts.

The scenario is straightforward: I am developing an analytics tool that hooks into a Google Analytics account and generates a report. I have a service account set up and verified and working with my own analytics account. My question is how to elegantly expand this so that incoming users can simply share permissions to their Google Analytics accounts with me, I can collect their data and pull up a report for them?

The confusion comes from the service account/OAuth 2.0 documentation. It seems that simplest thing I can do is create a client id and credentials, have users click a button, collect an authorization code and use it to generate an access and refresh token, then store the refresh token for later use. However, there also appears to be a means of using a service account that has permissions granted to is and simply changing the account id that I embed in the analytics query. There's also documentation of using Flow and Credential objects to perform authentication and access procedures.

I am mixing all of these up and can't get my bearings on what actually does what and with what limitations. Any help outlining the use cases and proper usages of these systems would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!